# The php 7 function with defined types returns an error related to the type

Tags: php, php-7

I have problem with my code:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

class TextModifications
{
    static public function readValue(string $string): string
    {
        return $purifier->purify($string);
    }

    static public function saveValue(string $string): string
    {
        return $string;
    }
}
$TextModifications = new TextModifications();
$TextModifications->saveValue($_POST["login"])
```

I have error:
**Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to TextModifications::saveValue() must be of the type string, null given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/1.php on line 21 and defined in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/1.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/1.php(21): TextModifications::saveValue(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/1.php on line 11**

I have PHP 7.2.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: What does a vardump of `$_POST["login"]` show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that you're passing a NULL as the first parameter to the function which requires a string parameter. Check if your variable `$_POST['login']` is null before calling the function or accept null values instead. It'll depend on where do you want to validate your input data.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52559759/2469308) by *@Ezequiel*, if you want to allow for handling of `null` value as input in the `saveValue` function, you can use `?` alongside `string`

It will be like the following:

```
static public function saveValue(?string $string): ?string
{
    return $string;
}
```

From [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php):

> Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked
> as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark. This
> signifies that as well as the specified type, NULL can be passed as an
> argument, or returned as a value, respectively.